# Equivalent java code to measure response time of server

Tags: c#, java, httprequest, response-time

what are the equivalent java api s that I should be using for the following C# code please? What i need is to check the response time.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
timer.Stop();
TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
//doSth.

long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

For more precision you could use `System.nanoTime()` which returns the nano seconds between two calls. Just note this: `This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond accuracy.`

A simple way to read from an URL and measure the speed might be:

```
 long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
 URL url = new URL(urlString);  
 url.getContent();
 long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

Comment: hi, thanks but what i need is equivalent for httpwebrequest and response in java

Answer (score 0):

look for an HttpURLConnection example like [this one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect).

Then use `System.nanotime()` to benchmark it